# Search query to fetch data

Tags: mysql, sql, swing, jdbc, plsql

I want write search query which fetch the data from students table based on multiple conditions like by ID , by name and by date of birth like that.
if I use OR condition like

```
Select * from students where Id='101' or name='Kumar' or age='21';
```

it will return if any one field is entered. If multiple fields are entered it will consider first only.
If I use AND condition like

```
Select * from students where Id='101' and name='Kumar' and age='21';
```

It will return only if all fields are entered. If any one of the field is empty it will return zero, I mean it will return empty. I want to get result even some fields are empty.

I'm using this quarry for swing application if I haven't enter text in one of the field then it will become empty like I'd='' not null 
How to get Result at this condition

```
Select * from students where Id='' and name='' and age='21'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get result even some fields are empty.

Then include that in your conditions.  Something like this:

```
WHERE
    (Id = '101' OR Id IS NULL) AND
    (name = 'Kumar' OR name IS NULL) AND
    (age = '21' OR age IS NULL)
```

Nesting conditions in parentheses allows you to build fairly complex conditional logic.  How you *define* that logic for finding the records you want to find is really up to you.

Comment: Thanks David see my requirement is different. I posted below

Comment: @ShimbuGowda: You should really update the *question* with additional information, not post it as an *answer*.  In any event, how does that change the requirement?  If you want to use an empty string in the condition instead of `NULL` then use an empty string.  You can put whatever logic you want in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` clause without `%`s. So it'll be acting as a simple `=`. Here's how it will work.

```
if(txtId.getText().equals("")){
  String id = "%%";
}else{
  String id = txtId.getText();
}

if(txtName.getText().equals("")){
  String name = "%%";
}else{
  String name = txtName.getText();
}

if(txtAge.getText().equals("")){
  String age = "%%";
}else{
  String age = txtAge.getText();
}

resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id LIKE '"+ id +"' and name LIKE '"+ name +"' and age LIKE '"+ age +"';");
```

Try this out. It'll work like a charm. (It's up to you to change the query according to your database)

Comment: If I use like I will get relative not exact one

Comment: No you won't. That's why i mentioned not to use `%`s. Try it first. Please mark as the correct answer if this works for you.